# What branch to git svn rebase on?

Tags: git, git-svn

Does it matter which local GIT branch I'm on when I do `git svn rebase`? A lot of times I'm on a local-only branch (like `trunk_work`) that I keep in sync with my local `trunk` branch, which maps to the upstream SVN branch. I always have to switch to `trunk` and then do the rebase, but I'm wondering if it works inside `trunk_work` too? It seems like this rebase isn't your typical rebase because git-svn is smart enough to know which local branches map to SVN branches and updates them all. But I want to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `git help svn`:

```
    rebase
       This fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and
       rebases the current (uncommitted to SVN) work against it.
```

...which I take to mean `git svn rebase` works on the current branch only, so it *does* matter which branch you are on.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I get confused with the log output from the `git svn fetch` it does as well, I think maybe that is the one that is updating all branches.